# How to inject HTML template at build time?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, gulp

I'm looking for a way to inject some HTML templates at build/compile time.
I'm working with Node.JS/Gulp but I can't find a plug-in/engine that just achieves this goal.
The idea would be to have an html file that would look like this :

```
<div data-template={src: 'templates/foo.html'} />
```

and foo.html would be injected automatically at compile time.
An extra constraint : each template (like *foo.html*) might itself be composed of other templates.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: At build time using node.js? How this?

Comment: with gulp, before doing some other compiler tasks (LESS, ...)